# EF 4 relationship in the same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I Have a Model like this,

My Menu entity have a relation 0..1 to 0..1 with the same entity (in themself) .. for have RootMenu recursively .. but I dont know how is the best way to saveChange with EF he always gave me errors..[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change that to 0..1 to 1, or 1 to 0..1 (depending on that direction the association goes). The PK is not nullable, so one side of the association has to be :1

Comment: "The PK is not nullable". But what if the FK is? (RootMenuId)